# Erro ao mostrar produtos em loja do magento

Tags: php, magento

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao clicar em um produto da loja:

> Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus

Já procurei no google e vi algumas soluções dizendo que era incompatibilidade de versão. Atualizei, mas o problema persiste.

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: O método "displayProductStockStatus" não existe no código fonte do Magento 1.7.0.2, por exemplo. Você consegue localizar em que módulo e arquivo está essa chamada?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que você andou instalando um módulo incompatível com sua versão do Magento, hein?

> Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus

É algum módulo para exibir quantidade do produto em estoque na página do produto? Se for isso mesmo, não precisa de módulo, use a dica do blog: http://mariosam.com.br/magento/exibir-estoque-frontend/.

Para resolver seu problema, desinstale o módulo.